# How do I install Atheros AR9271 wifi drivers on Debian?

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, usb

I am trying to use a USB connected device (a used wlan adapter, that I got without any docs or CD). When I plug it and run `lsusb` I see it gets recognized as plugged. What do I do to use it?

The line is:

`Bus 001 Device 021: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n`

Comment: If it's a random USB wifi dongle, it might not be supported in Linux. Even if it is supported, the installation procedure varies a lot from device to device, so it is not possible to answer your question generically.

Comment: Based on the device ID, it looks like it should be supported by the [ath9k_htc](https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc)  driver (although, on Debian, you may need to install non-free firmware)

Comment: @steeldriver: apparently there's open firmware for it: https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc/open_firmware

Comment: On desktop Ubuntu 18.10 when I plug in my Qualcomm Atheros AR9271 USB dongle this network adapter auto shows up as a pickable adapter in network settings without needing to install driver

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a `non-free` repository to your `sources.list` then install the `firmware-atheros` , plug in your device it will be loaded automatically.

1)  Edit your `sources.list`:

```
apt edit-sources
```

Choose your favorite text editor ( e,g: 1=`nano`). Add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

2) install the `firmware-atheros` package:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

3) Connect your device

Comment: How do you apt-get when you have no network?

Comment: You missed this: 1.- The Repo should be https 2-When you do apt-get update the system will complain if keys aren't present, add them using instructions here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/118944

Comment: @eco this Debian not Ubuntu.

Comment: @GAD3R Correct, but ubuntu is based of of Debian so I was piggy bagging of  of your post and forgot to delete mine. Btw, consider this for both: https://askubuntu.com/questions/799104/unable-to-get-linksys-wusb6100m-wireless-adapter-to-work

Answer (score 2):

With the output of `lsusb` you can use $SEARCH_ENGINE for "AR9271", which then leads you to [a guide how to `apt-get install firmware-atheros`](https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc), which luckily lists your devices ID (-: